# EFCore tracking external database changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a website that has data constantly changing on a database that i need to display within the view in real time. EFCore already keeps up to date with any changes on the database but i'm not finding any trigger/way of tracking when something changes so i can update it in the view. EFCore has their ChangeTracker but its only tracking changes on the client side that are unsaved changes to entities. i need a way to track/receive a trigger on client side when an external changes happen to the database. does EFCore have something built in for this?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And also *"EFCore already keeps up to date with any changes on the database*" is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Entity Developer, by Devart, it allows for a trigger to update the model as the db changes, plus a version of it is free.